# Why I cannot call a parameterized constructor with generics if I specify the base class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constructor, compiler-errors

If have the following class:

```
class A
{
    public A(int number)
    {
    }
}
```

Then why I cannot have a generic class like this one:

```
class B<ParameterClass> where ParameterClass : A
{
    public B()
    {
        ParameterClass a = new ParameterClass(1);
    }
}
```

I get a CS0304 and the compiler says that I haven't the new() restriction but I just want to call a constructor that's defined on A and as ParameterClass will be always an A the compiler can be sure that the A(int number) constructor will be always present. I just don't get why there is this restriction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because the constructor is declared on `A` doesn't mean it will be declared on `ParameterClass`. For example:

```
public class Bad : A
{
    public Bad(string x) : base(x.Length)
    {
    }
}
```

Now I use:

```
var b = new B<Bad>();
```

What would you expect that to do? The way you've written it, if it *were* valid I'd expect it to try to call `new Bad(1)`, which certainly isn't valid.

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding generics.

`ParameterClass` will not always be `A`.
Rather, it will always be `A` **or a type that inherits `A`**.

Types that inherit `A` do not necessarily have the same constructors as `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `where` clause to restrict the parameter type so that you know it will have certain methods. You still wouldn't be able to construct it this way because a class that inherits A may not have such a constructor.

How about passing an instance of A to B's constructor alongside the `where ParameterClass: A` in the declaration